# On scroll move to next section

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am building a website and I would like to have it move to the next section automatically when the user is scrolling in between them using html/css and js.

A perfect exemple is on the tesla website: https://www.tesla.com/ as soon as u scroll out even once of the section the website will automatically move down to the next or previous section.

I am having a hard time finding documentation for this online if anybody could tell me how to achieve this, thanks

Comment: Investigating intersectionObserver could be very helpful here. If you could put up a short snippet showing the sort of thing you are considering it would help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a setup for you that checks if you need to scroll to the next section or previous section.

I hope you can create the rest from this setup

```js
var lastScrollLocation = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > lastScrollLocation) {
    lastScrollLocation = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log("next section");
  } else {
    lastScrollLocation = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log("previous section");
  }
});
```

```css
.container section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.container section p {
   margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <p>
      Section #1
    </p>

  </section>

  <section>
    <p>
      Section #2
    </p>
  </section>

  <section>
    <p>
      Section #3
    </p>
  </section>

  <section>
    <p>
      Section #4
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```